# mvc:resources mapping a specific jar file

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am using Spring MVC, and in the configuration I am using the following line to make some Javascript files available to my application:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/,classpath:/META-INF/" />
```

However, I am concerned that this may lead to security issues, unforeseen circumstances, etc. because every single jar on my classpath (and there are many!) that have a META-INF folder will be accessible from /resources/ to a user who is poking around.

Is there a way to only map the location to a specific jar file. In my case, it would be Spring-JS jar located at the following location (relative to the root of my Eclipse workspace):

```
/Jars/spring 3.0.5/spring-js-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead restrict the specific locations exposed. For eg, for spring-js jar you can do this:

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/web-resources" />`

I doubt if you can specify the exact jar though.